# XamlFlair Animation bind on Grid.Canvas prop

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

Im using XamlFlair package to animate some elements. I want to bind animation  Yoffset on actualHeight of the Canvas in the Grid.
Error seems to be that mainCanvas cannot be found

The code looks like this :

```
<Grid x:Name="mainGrid">
<Grid.Resources>
            <xf:AnimationSettings x:Key="MoveInXY1" Kind="TranslateXTo,TranslateYFrom"
OffsetX="-200"  OffsetY="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,AncestorType={x:Type Canvas}}, Path=ActualHeight}"  Duration="500"/>

</Grid.Resources>
<Grid>
<Canvas x:Name="mainCanvas">
<UserControl "Animations ....'/>
<UserControl "Animations ....'/>
<UserControl "Animations ....'/>
</Canvas>
</Grid>
```

Any help is highly appreciated.
Thank you,

Comment: you can try：OffsetY="{Binding ElementName=mainCanvas,AncestorType={x:Type Canvas}}, Path=ActualHeight}"

Comment: nope cannot bind on anything Cannot find Governing element